# How can I record audio from the microphone with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, audio-recording

I need a way to record sounds from the microphone with ffmpeg. How can I do it ?

Comment: @duDE I used this code 'ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone" output.mp3' but I get 'Could not find audio only device with name [Microphone] among source devices of type audio.'

Comment: You can list your devices with: ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

Comment: @duDE - You should submit that as answer since it seems to answer the author's question.  This comment is being submitted through the review of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at this Wiki: [FFmpeg / Capture / Desktop](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)

> You can list your devices with:
>
> `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

Comment: `  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Unrecognized option 'list_devices'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: Unrecognized option 'list_devices'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing tip. For my computer (Windows OS): "ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -audio "Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)" show_region 1 -i desktop output.mkv" inducing error of  "Unrecognized option 'audio'"...Any suggestion?