# How to convert mp4 to avi?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mp4 file.
How to convert my file.mp4 file to file.avi using ffmpeg without loss quality?
I don't know what should I do in order to convert mp4 to avi.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will help u.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.avi
```

Comment: Other way around, he's converting mp4 to avi.

Comment: @tetech, answer was updated

Comment: @Nikto, it works good. Thanks

Comment: This technically works, but if a player requires .avi format, then the question is whether it'll actually support the H.264 codec that most newer .mp4 files are using... (I wouldn't be surprised if it only accepted things like MPEG-2 and Xvid in those .avi files.)

Comment: @user1686, i don't know how to convert avi to mp4 with another command. Can u help me in my question, pls?https://superuser.com/questions/1580982/screen-recording-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Pretty sure this does nothing, might as well just change the file extension as its the same codec