# How do I capture playback audio AND video?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

So I want to record my screen and my playback audio.

The only 'solution' I've found is recording my microphone, rather than the audio played back from my screen.

When I do `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`, I don't get my the name for the playback thing (It does work when I use the Control Panel).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen recording using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1580982/screen-recording-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: Your last question got flagged as duplicate, and linked with at least 3 different questions which contain the answer to your question. That doesn't mean that you should simply ask the exact same question again. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1580982/screen-recording-using-ffmpeg) you can find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the "Stereo Mixer". Press **Windows + R** to open run command, type mmsys.cpl and press ENTER. Click the recording tab, right click on the area where the devices are and make sure "Disabled Devices" & "Disconnected Devices" are ticked. Then Enable the Stereo Mixer.

If you still don't see stereo mixer on the list after enabling disabled & disconnected devices you may have to download the sound drivers on the manufacturer site of your computer rather than using the drivers downloaded by  Microsoft (Windows Update).

[image: https://i.ibb.co/mNqSr7K/Stereo-Mix.gif]

Next you do the list devices command again, grab the stereo mixer device and use it with something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 20 -i desktop -f dshow -i "audio=Mixagem estéreo (Conexant SmartAudio HD)" -c:a aac "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Even after doing all this any record I make is still silence.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the drivers of your motherboard, the ones refering to sound?

Comment: Windows 10 already installed the drivers automatically. (It's a laptop FWIW). In any case, it seems the only way to record sound is to tell Windows Capture the app is a game (it's actually a Chrome tab), capture with video and audio, then strip off the video.  I've tried several other method including Audacity and none of them work.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently you have to actually close the above dialog before it works, as the dialog appears to be "using" the mixer and doesn't let anything else use it.  I guess Windows Capture gets around that somehow.